# Enable / Disable Blur Effect On Timestamp

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am using Davinci Resolve to cut and edit dashcam videos. I use power windows and nodes to blur out tracked license plates. However, in many occasions, I need the blur to be active / deactive on certain times (eg when the car is too far gone).

How can I achieve that result with Davinci?

Comment: so my understanding is when a license plate goes out of frame and comes back into frame the blur is gone? if this is the case, i would either manually keyframe the power window or just use fusion (using the planar tracking node, a mask node, and a blur node)